# jQuery keep parent highlight on submenu hidden navigation arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

I need some help in jQuery and I really hope that I could find some help here. I would like when I use my navigation arrows (next/previous) when I am on a hidden item that the parent item stays highlight. For the first item home, it works but for the rest not. Does anybody can help me please?

**[here my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/eWdQ5/2/)**

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <ul class="hide"><li><a href="#home2"></a></li></ul>
        <li><a href="#newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>
... </div>
```

I tried to fiddle something :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cssmenu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');

       //adding the state for this parent menu
       $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');


});
```

I manage my next and previous button like that :

```
$( "#next, #prev" ).click( function ( event ) {
            var
                positionActiveClass = menu.find( "> li.active" ).index(),
                menuLength = menu.find( "> li" ).length - 1,
                buttonId = $( this ).attr( "id" );

            if ( buttonId === "next" ) {
                if ( positionActiveClass === ( menuLength ) ) {
                    newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( 0 );
                    newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                    animation( newPositionActiveClass );
                } else {
                    newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( positionActiveClass + 1 );
                    newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                    animation( newPositionActiveClass );
                }
            } else {
                if ( positionActiveClass === 0 ) {
                    newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( menuLength );
                    newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                    animation( newPositionActiveClass );
                } else {
                    newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( positionActiveClass - 1 );
                    newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                    animation( newPositionActiveClass );
                }
            }

            event.preventDefault();
        } );
```

Comment: Cannot read your entire code but I can tell you that you are doing simple thing in a very ambiguous way.

Comment: Hi Aamir, thanks for your reply. Did you took a look at my fiddle ? Actually, for example, I want to simulate the continuity of an item, home2 is a continuity of home. The problem, when I click next, home stays hightlighted, which ok, but I stayed blocked on the hidden home2. I can't go to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra ul after the first li which has a class hide. What is that for? Just remove that ul and everything works fine.

Comment: Hi, yes I added this ul class hide after the first li in order to have home stil active when we are in home2. home2 is a continuity of home and I want that the user thinks that he is still in home. But the problem, when I am in home2 the navigation is blocked.